# создание базы данных в txt файле через vbs

Tags: парсер, vbscript

Существует файл baza.txt. В нем могут быть строки с пробелами

```
name: qw er
pass: 12 34
```

Или

```
name = qw er
pass = 12 34
```

Я не знаю как обрабатывает файлы vbs, в каком контексте используется ":" или "=". Нужен скрипт vbs, который будет парсить этот файл baza.txt.

```
Poisk = inputbox ("что искать")
```

И он выдает значение в

```
InputBox "Окно для копирования", "Imya", Poisk
```

Если файла baza.txt не существует он его создаст. Я смогу изменить эти значения, те что после ":" или "=".

получилось чтото вроде

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if FSO.FileExists("1.txt") Then

Set ts = FSO.OpenTextFile("1.txt", 2, false) 'открыть

else

Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile("1.txt", 2, false) 'создать

end if

'извлечение из файла

'set readname = Split(whole_line, "Name: ")(1)
'set readpass = Split(whole_line, "Pass: ")(1)

'добавляет переменные name1 и pass1
name1 = inputbox ("Name:","База данных",readname)
pass1 = inputbox ("Pass:","База данных",readpass)
'записывание переменных в файл
ts.WriteLine("Name: " &name1)
ts.WriteLine("Pass: " &pass1)
```

но он удаляет предыдущее значение. можно ли как нибудь извлечь readname и readpass до перезаписывания 1.txt?

Comment: *Я не знаю как обрабатывает файлы vbs* А как напишете, так и обработает. *в каком контексте используется ":" или "="* Да ни в каком. Символ - он символ и есть. То же касается и пробелов, кстати.

Comment: @Akina как сделать базу данных не через bat а через vbs

Comment: Что значит "как"? берёте и пишете код. Для поставленной задачи лучше FileSystemObject.File.ReadAll, потом либо Split в массив и по нему тупо в цикле искать, либо искать прямо в прочитанном, а от найденного - vbNewLine в обе стороны. Если надо искать по имени параметра, и он уникален в файле - массив лучше перегнать в коллекцию.

Comment: Это понятно, в bat можно использовать
    'if /i "%%a"=="Pass:" set pass=%%b',
как сделать это в vbs

Comment: Я же сказал - загнать в коллекцию, используя имя параметра как ключ. И потом по нему получать значение. `Collection.Add data(i), Split(data(i), ":")(0)` и `value = Collection("key")` (либо `value = Split(Collection("key"), ":")(1)`).

Comment: Впрочем, я рекомендую сразу после считывания заменить используемый сепаратор (`:`, `=`) на `CHR(0)` (само собой только первый в строке). И выполнить обратную замену при сохранении. Ну чисто на случай, что символ-сепаратор вдруг да попадётся в значении.

Comment: @Akina хорошо, как искать слова я разобрался. как вставлять тоже. но как сделать так чтобы можно было редактировать файл после `name: `, те в `OpenTextFile(<Filename>,<Iomode>,<Create>,<Format>)` есть читать, редактировать с полным удалением, добавить в конце.

Comment: Ну вот строка прочитана, поделена на имя параметра и значение параметра, и положена в какую-то переменную (коллекцию, к примеру). Юзер указывает имя параметра, этот параметр ищется, и его значение выводится юзеру на редактирование (скажем, в инпутбоксе). Принятое изменённое значение сохраняется в переменной вместо старого. А по завершении правок старый файл удаляем/переименуем, и создаём новый, в который пишем новые значения всех параметров.

Comment: @Akina почти готово, осталось только извлечь то что находится после `name: ` и `pass: ` и вывести их через `name=InputBox("Имя","Baza.txt","ВВОДИТЕ")` а вместо "вводите" должно быть значение `na me1`, которое до этого было извлечено из файла baza.txt. Как извлечь то что находится после `name: ` ?

Comment: `Split(whole_line, ":")(1)`

Comment: @Akina Что дальше

Comment: @Akina все равно не получается

Comment: @Akina `Split(whole_line, ":")(1)` будет извлекать построчно все значения после знака `:` a мне нужно извлечь то что после значений `Name: ` и `Pass: ` в разные переменные, отдельно

Comment: Ну так извлекай и сравнивай - кто мешает? что, я тебе отлаживать программу буду? тут не форум, тут подобные вещи - неформат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Dim strSourceFile

Dim objFSO
Dim strContent

Dim strNameValue
Dim strPasswordValue


strSourceFile = "baza.txt"


Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FileExists(strSourceFile) Then
With objFSO.OpenTextFile(strSourceFile)
    strContent = .ReadAll()
    .Close
End With

strNameValue     = GetValue(strContent, "Name")
strPasswordValue = GetValue(strContent, "Pass")

strNameValue     = Trim(InputBox("Enter name:",     "Enter name",     strNameValue))
strPasswordValue = Trim(InputBox("Enter password:", "Enter password", strPasswordValue))

If Len(strNameValue) > 0 Then
    strContent = SetValue(strContent, "Name", strNameValue)
End If

If Len(strPasswordValue) > 0 Then
    strContent = SetValue(strContent, "Pass", strPasswordValue)
End If

With objFSO.CreateTextFile(strSourceFile, True)
    .Write strContent
    .Close
End With
Else
WScript.Echo "Can't find source file [" & strSourceFile & "]."
Set ts = objFSO.CreateTextFile("baza.txt", 2, false)
ts.WriteLine("Name: ")
ts.WriteLine("Pass: ")
WScript.Quit 2
End If

Set objFSO = Nothing

WScript.Quit 0
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetValue(strContent, strParameter)
With WScript.CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine  = True

    .Pattern = "^\s*" & strParameter & ": (.*?)$"

    If .Test(strContent) Then
        GetValue = .Execute(strContent).Item(0).Submatches.Item(0)
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Can't find parameter [" & strParameter & "] in source file [" & strSourceFile & "]."
        GetValue = ""
    End If
End With
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function SetValue(strContent, strParameter, strValue)
With WScript.CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine  = True

    .Pattern = "^\s*" & strParameter & ": .*?$"

    If .Test(strContent) Then
        SetValue = .Replace(strContent, strParameter & ": " & strValue)
    Else
        SetValue = strContent & vbCrLf & strParameter & ": " & strValue
    End If
End With
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```